# Adding a UITableView to a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to embed a `UITableView` into a `UICollectionViewCell`. I'm managing to get everything to load. However, when it does load it up it seems to randomly use the last loaded value for the `UITableView` List Items. My `DebugPrint` Output seems to load all of the `CollectionViewCells` before even referencing the TableView. Once the CollectionViewCells are set, then it populates the TableView with whatever value it is left with. How can I resolve this so that I'm using the correct values? I suspect it is something to how I'm using `IndexPath` however I'm fairly new to Swift.

[image: Example WireFrame]

Populating UICollectionView

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: releaseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ReleaseCollectionViewCell

        let vid: VideoItem
        vid = Video[indexPath.item]

        let rating = vid.Rating
        let denominator = 2.0
        let roundedRating = round(rating*denominator )/denominator

        if vid.SiteVideoID != 0 {
            cell.ReleaseImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: "\(file.BaseURL)/sitePictures/\(GetFilePath(ID: String(vid.SiteVideoID)))/\(String(vid.SiteVideoID)).jpg")
        } else {
            cell.ReleaseImage.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: "\(file.BaseURL)/pictures/\(GetFilePath(ID: String(vid.VideoID)))/\(String(vid.VideoID))_001.png")
        }

        cell.ReleaseDate.text = vid.ReleaseDate
        cell.ReleaseTitle.text = vid.Title

        cell.SiteLogo.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: "\(file.BaseURL)/siteLogos/" + String(vid.SiteID) + ".png")

        if vid.VideoID == 0 {
            cell.ReleaseImage.alpha = 0.5
        } else {
            cell.ReleaseImage.alpha = 1.0
        }

        indexPathItem = -1
        indexPathItem = indexPath.item
        debugPrint(indexPathItem)

        cell.TagsView.delegate = self
        cell.TagsView.dataSource = self
   return cell
}
```

and for populating the TableView

```
extension MiscCollectionViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if indexPathItem != -1 {
            return Video[indexPathItem].Tags.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let tags = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Tag", for: indexPath) as! TagTableViewCell
            debugPrint(String(indexPathItem) + " " + Video[indexPathItem].Tags[indexPath.row])
            tags.TagLabel.text = String(indexPathItem) //Video[indexPathItem].Tags[indexPath.row]

            return tags
        }
}
```

Comment: How many collection view cells are there? Because if the number is fixed and less, I would recommend using a few views instead of a collection view.

Comment: @Damon It can be up to 500 depending on the result set from the database

Comment: Try tableview.reload() before the return cell statement of the Collection View's cellForItemAt method.

Comment: @Damon it won't build if I put it in the `func collectionView` or did you mean the `tableview`?

Comment: @Damon - update added `cell.TagsView.reloadData()` before the `return cell` and got the same result unfortunately. Interestingly though, the number of rows being returned seem to be correct. It is just the values of the rows that are wrong

Comment: More interesting. The values seem to be correct when scrolling through the list, but they're incorrect when the view loads up